# Mean square error

Tags: variance, mean, bias, mse

anyone can help me explane  :
[image]

I don't understand formula 2. Why transform from formula 1 to 2.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The MSE of an estimator, $\hat{\alpha}$, of an unknown parameter $\alpha$ is:

$$\text{MSE}(\hat{\alpha})=\mathbb{E}\Big[(\hat{\alpha}-\alpha)^{2}\Big]$$

We can formulate the other representation as follows:

$$\begin{align}
\text{MSE}(\hat{\alpha})&=\mathbb{E}\Big[(\hat{\alpha}-\alpha)^{2}\Big]\\
&=\mathbb{E}\Big[(\hat{\alpha}-\mathbb{E}[\hat{\alpha}]+\mathbb{E}[\hat{\alpha}]+\alpha)^{2}\Big]\\
&=\mathbb{E}\Big[\big(\hat{\alpha}-\mathbb{E}[\hat{\alpha}]\big)^{2}+2\big(\hat{\alpha}-\mathbb{E}[\hat{\alpha}]\big)\big(\mathbb{E}[\hat{\alpha}]-\alpha\big)+\big(\mathbb{E}[\hat{\alpha}]-\alpha\big)^{2}\Big]\\
&=\mathbb{E}\Big[\big(\hat{\alpha}-\mathbb{E}[\hat{\alpha}]\big)^{2}\Big]+\mathbb{E}\Big[2\big(\hat{\alpha}-\mathbb{E}[\hat{\alpha}]\big)\big(\mathbb{E}[\hat{\alpha}]-\alpha\big)\Big]+\mathbb{E}\Big[\big(\mathbb{E}[\hat{\alpha}]-\alpha\big)^{2}\Big]\\
&=\mathbb{E}\Big[\big(\hat{\alpha}-\mathbb{E}[\hat{\alpha}]\big)^{2}\Big]
+2\big(\mathbb{E}[\hat{\alpha}]-\alpha\big)\mathbb{E}\Big[\big(\hat{\alpha}-\mathbb{E}[\hat{\alpha}]\big)\Big]
+\big(\mathbb{E}[\hat{\alpha}]-\alpha\big)^{2}\\
&=\mathbb{E}\Big[\big(\hat{\alpha}-\mathbb{E}[\hat{\alpha}]\big)^{2}\Big]
+2\big(\mathbb{E}[\hat{\alpha}]-\alpha\big)\big(\mathbb{E}[\hat{\alpha}]-\mathbb{E}[\hat{\alpha}]\big)
+\big(\mathbb{E}[\hat{\alpha}]-\alpha\big)^{2}\\
&=\mathbb{E}\Big[\big(\hat{\alpha}-\mathbb{E}[\hat{\alpha}]\big)^{2}\Big]
+\big(\mathbb{E}[\hat{\alpha}]-\alpha\big)^{2}\\
&=\text{Var}(\hat{\alpha})+\text{Bias}(\hat{\alpha},\alpha)^{2}
\end{align}$$

Essentially, the purpose of the second representation is that it is a convenient way to calculate the MSE. It also tells us that in the case of unbiased estimators, the MSE and variance are the same.

Comment: @conannhoc If you're happy with the answer, you can mark it as accepted.